# jquery append with nested loop

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through this array but, it is not giving me the correct output.

This is my array

```
var check_list_items = [
  {
    main_point: 'Engagement',
    sub_points:[
    '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 1</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 2</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 3</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 4</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 5</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 6</li>'
    ]
  },
  {
    main_point: 'Case Review',
    sub_points:[
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Case Review sub point 1</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Case Review sub point 2</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Case Review sub point 3</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Case Review sub point 4</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Case Review sub point 5</li>'
    ]
  },
  {
    main_point: 'ADR',
    sub_points:[
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR sub point 1</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR sub point 2</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR sub point 3</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR sub point 4</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR sub point 5</li>'
    ]
  },
  {
    main_point: 'ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal ',
    sub_points:[
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 1</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 2</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 3</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 4</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 5</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 6</li>'

    ]
  },
  {
    main_point: 'Tribunal',
    sub_points:[
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Tribunal sub point 1</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Tribunal sub point 2</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Tribunal sub point 3</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Tribunal sub point 4</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Tribunal sub point 5</li>'

    ]
  },
  {
    main_point: 'Finalisation',
    sub_points:[
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 1</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 2</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 3</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 4</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 5</li>',
    '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 6</li>'

    ]
  },
  ];
```

and this is my loop using jquery
// now loop through these item and show them

```
  $.each(check_list_items,function (index, item) {
    $('#check_list_items').append(`
      <div class="col-6">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/folder_icons/tick.png'); ?>" class="tick-icon" alt="">
        <div class="tick-empty"></div>
        <div class="card step6_card" >
          <div class="card-header step6_header1" >
            ${item.main_point}
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            ${item.sub_points }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
  });
```

I expect jquery nested looping should be easy like vue js

Answer (score 0):

Use `.join("")` on the `sub_points` array to join the `<li>` elements together. By outputting `${item.sub_points}` without `join` it will automatically concatenate the values with a comma—the equivalent of using `.join(",")`.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0on3sphw/

Comment: I have another problem. I have this array

Answer (score 0):

There are some modifications that you should do with your code:

1. Create as final HTML string in JS as possible, before appending. Appending HTML string to a DOM element is a resource consuming process compared to adding some new substring to a JS string.
2. Watch out for ', ", `, etc - they should always come in pairs :)

```js
const check_list_items = [{
    main_point: 'Engagement',
    sub_points: [
      '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 1</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 2</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 3</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 4</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 5</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">engagement sub point 6</li>'
    ]
  },
  {
    main_point: 'Case Review',
    sub_points: [
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Case Review sub point 1</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Case Review sub point 2</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Case Review sub point 3</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Case Review sub point 4</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Case Review sub point 5</li>'
    ]
  },
  {
    main_point: 'ADR',
    sub_points: [
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR sub point 1</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR sub point 2</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR sub point 3</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR sub point 4</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR sub point 5</li>'
    ]
  },
  {
    main_point: 'ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal ',
    sub_points: [
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 1</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 2</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 3</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 4</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 5</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">ADR-VAT Tribunal Appeal  sub point 6</li>'

    ]
  },
  {
    main_point: 'Tribunal',
    sub_points: [
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Tribunal sub point 1</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Tribunal sub point 2</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Tribunal sub point 3</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Tribunal sub point 4</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Tribunal sub point 5</li>'

    ]
  },
  {
    main_point: 'Finalisation',
    sub_points: [
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 1</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 2</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 3</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 4</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 5</li>',
      '<li class="list-group-item ">Finalisation sub point 6</li>'

    ]
  },
];

// only append finalized HTML string
$('#check_list_items').append(appendHtml(check_list_items))

function appendHtml(list) {
  // create the final HTML string in JS,
  // before appending it
  let html = ''
  list.forEach(item => {
    html += createHtml(item)
  })

  return html

}

function createHtml(item) {

  let html = ''

  html += `<div class="col-6">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/folder_icons/tick.png'); ?>" class="tick-icon" alt="">
      <div class="tick-empty"></div>
      <div class="card step6_card" >
        <div class="card-header step6_header1" >
          ${item.main_point}
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          ${item.sub_points.join('')}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>`

  return html

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check_list_items"></div>
```